# Android Custom Map linked to real co-ordinates best implementation

Tags: android, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I was wondering how could i relate a custom map for a specific zone with real google map co-ordinates.

For example i have an autocad drawing of a specific place that i want to link it with real co-ordinates.

Doing a direct overlay won't be the best option since i want to display only this specific zone and not the rest of the google map for example.